# How to stack a char[] inside a structure in C++

Tags: c++

I have been beating my head over this for a while now. I can't find any proper reference to this online.

I have a structure with char data[] inside it. Say for example -

```
struct mystruct
{
    char mydata[];
};
```

How do I create a `mystruct` variable with length of data whatever I want.

This works-

```
mystruct my {"Test"};
```

But how do I do it with another variable.

```
char data[] = "Test";
mystruct my {data}; // this doesn't work as data becomes char* and there is a type mismatch
```

How do I assign data to mydata in a c++ way?

Edit: Assume the structure is coming from a 3rd party library and cannot be changed

Comment: That struct definition is invalid. You need to specify a size for `mydata`.

Comment: @interjay so you are saying it's not possible to do what I want to do, without any malloc/ new mumbo jumbo.

Comment: You use `std::string` instead of a plain-old-array... The idiom you are using is valid in C with `mydata[];` as a FAM (*Flexible Array Member*) -- but that isn't for the case you are attempting to use it in... (and even for the correct use, there are fairly arduous constraints on how you can use `mystruct` thereafter). Best to just know -- not for C++ if you are learning C++.

Comment: I'm saying that the struct definition you showed won't compile, so you'd need to change it anyway.

Comment: @interjay it compiles fine in msvc.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Thank you, this is what I was looking for - FAM. Can you put that as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: Sure, give me a second to write it up.

Comment: It doesn't compile in gcc or clang.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `mystruct` you declare `char mydata[];` as an incomplete type (an array, but not how-many). The specific use of an object of that type comes from C. By allowing an array of incomplete type as the last member of a struct, in C this provides you with the ability to dynamically allocate storage for the struct itself, plus whatever amount of storage you want for `mydata[]` and then be able to access the information through `mydata[]`.

This is formally a *Flexible Array Member* (a FAM), and it must be the final member of the struct where other members are also present, and thereafter the struct cannot be part of another struct or an array-of-struct because there will be only one FAM allowed in any structure object that makes use of a FAM.

What was confusing is your tag [c++] which would not provide a FAM for use, this is strictly a C idiom.

I hope this provides the information you needed. If you have further questions, please just drop a comment below. Good luck with your coding.

Comment: I was wondering if this was a valid paradigm in c++. But as you made it clear it's not. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Any assembly-level 'length' is compile-time in C++, it cannot be changed at run time.
Instead, you use a `std::vector<>` which allocates memory dynamically. Or you can use `std::any` to hold whatever variable you want.

Basically, you are mixing pointers which is dangerous. Your data[] does not hold the "string" but points to it. It won't work in copying and required semantics in containers etc.

Just forget about all and use STL.

```
struct data
{ 
    std::vector<char> member1;
    std::any member2;
    std::string member3;
};
```

All problems efficiently and correctly solved.

Comment: Yeah I mean I can do that. But assume I cannot change this struct. Is it possible at all? Maybe creating a unique_ptr with allocation.

Comment: But if you can't change the struct, how can you store a unique_ptr in it ?

Comment: I just want to instantiate the struct and make `mydata` point to `data`. I prefer `my` to be a stack variable, but a smart pointer is also fine I guess.

Comment: Use a void* pointer then which can be cast to anything.

Comment: `mydata` is not a pointer. It's invalid C++, but in C it would be a flexible array member, that is an actual array that spills into over-allocated storage in a well-defined manner. The  solution is either to design an interop layer with a C-compiled backend that performs the allocation and accesses, or see if your compiler has an extension to use FAMs in C++.